# NodeJS Server Uploading Large Files with Multer in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am able to upload very large files (12-15GB) when running my NodeJS server locally using multer.  However, I'm having trouble getting large files to upload when deploying the node server on AWS.

When the node server is deployed, I **can** upload small files, but when uploading large files it hangs and never returns until I kill the node server.  This seems like an environment issue inherent to being on AWS because I never get this problem locally.

In AWS I have my node server deployed on a t2.micro Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.

Is there something I'm missing fundamentally about AWS setup when transferring large files over the network?  Some file limit somewhere?  Something with Windows Firewall or a setting in my AWS profile?

Since I have been able to FTP any size file to my AWS server, I didn't think there was a file limit size imposed.  So I'm inclined to believe it's probably some other issue.

Let me know if any further information is needed to help out with this if it's not obvious immediately.

Here is the multer part of my nodejs code in case that helps.

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Archive/' + req.body.destination)
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

let upload = multer({ storage });

export default ({ config, db }) => {
    let api = Router();

    var cpUpload = upload.fields([
        { name: 'destination' },
        { name: 'files' }])
    api.post('/upload', cpUpload, function (req, res, next) {
        res.json(req.files);
    });

    return api;
}
```

Comment: You said that you upload files up to 12-15 GB in size. You also said that you're using t2.micro, which storage is EBS 30GB base, and up to 16 TB. I'm not sure that it resizes automatically if needed. Are you sure you have enough space left on the storage?

Comment: I had increased my volume size on disk to be around 100GB, so it has plenty of space